# PHP ParseUser::getCurrentUser(); doesn't work outside of login page

Tags: php, authentication, parse-platform

I can log the user in just fine, and display the username.

```
<?php 
require 'connectParse.php'; 

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();


// set session storage
ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );

try {
  $user = ParseUser::logIn("user", "pass");
  // Do stuff after successful login.
} catch (ParseException $error) {
  // The login failed. Check error to see why.
}

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
$currentUser = $currentUser->get("username");
echo $currentUser;
?>

<a href="/second.php">second page</a>
```

But when I navigate the user to another page on the same server, and check for a current user, I get nothing.

```
<?php

require 'connectParse.php'; 

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser(); 
print_r( "<p>" . $currentUser . " </p><p>is the user</p>" );

?>
```

Those are the only pieces of code on both the login and other page. I've tried with and without the session_start(); on the second page as well. And of course, the user does exist on the other page. Spent a good amount of hours and haven't gotten anywhere with this. I can hack around it setting my own SESSION variables but I want to use the functionality of Parse. I figure it is something really simple that I am missing... would love love love any help out there! Thank you and cheers!

Comment: Hello,

You can set "session.auto_start" to "1" in php.ini instead of calling session_start each time.
Or you can only put session_start at the top of file before "require 'connectParse.php'".

Thanks

Comment: Hey Thomas, I'm facing the exact same issue - did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start the session AFTER have included the autoloader. This to avoid the problem of incomplete classes. The `Parse\ParseUser` had not been loaded yet, when PHP tried to deserialize the object in the session.

Call `session_start();` after `require '../vendor/autoload.php';` and BEFORE `ParseClient::initialize('app_id', 'key', 'masterkey');`.

You don't need to use `ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );` as if the session is active ParseClient::initialize will use it by default.

Then you could get the current user. That's all.

Comment: I did what you said and am still experiencing the same problem. Should the `initialize` be present with every page? I have updated my "Answer"

Comment: Ignore my comment above. You are right. It was a problem with the session issue. To whomever runs into this problem again. Check your `php.ini` and make sure that `session.auto_start` is not enabled (`1`). Even though I did what @Laxus said, it still ran into the same problem until I turned that off.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer but some debugging help**

Maybe someone will figure it out

I am also running to this issue. I have been able to decipher the following.

The $_SESSION data is actually changing between page.

On the login page I have added `print_r($_SESSION)` as well as on a completely different page. The following two lines are the results of them respectively

**Login Page:**

```
Array ( [parseData] => Array ( [user] => Parse\ParseUser Object ( [_sessionToken:protected] => someProtectedToken [serverData:protected] => Array ( [email] => firstName@email.com [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => firstName lastName [isBand] => [username] => firstName@email.com ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [email] => firstName@email.com [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => firstName lastName [isBand] => [username] => firstName@email.com ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [email] => 1 [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => 1 [isBand] => 1 [sessionToken] => 1 [username] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => GVw0Thu61i [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-12-31 21:51:26 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-12-31 21:51:51 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) ) )
```

**some random page:**

```
Array ( [parseData] => Array ( [user] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object ( [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Parse\ParseUser [_sessionToken:protected] => someProtectedToken [serverData:protected] => Array ( [email] => firstName@email.com [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => firstName lastName [isBand] => [username] => firstName@email.com ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [email] => firstName@email.com [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => firstName lastName [isBand] => [username] => firstName@email.com ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [email] => 1 [emailVerified] => 1 [firstlast] => 1 [isBand] => 1 [sessionToken] => 1 [username] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => _User [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => GVw0Thu61i [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-12-31 21:51:26 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-12-31 21:51:51 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) ) )
```

note that `[user] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object`

**Code: login.php**

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
include 'head.php';
include 'nav.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;

use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

ParseClient::initialize('a', 'b', 'c');




$name = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


try {
  $user = ParseUser::logIn($name, $password);
    echo "you are in. hello: " .ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->get("firstlast") ;
} catch (ParseException $error) {
  echo "wrong info";
}

include 'foot.php';
```

**CODE: For the random page**

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;

use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

ParseClient::initialize('app_id', 'key', 'masterkey');

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Comment: Put `session_start();` after `require '../vendor/autoload.php';` and before `ParseClient::initialize`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a duplicate of this question here: [User not recognized through Parse\ParseUser, but exists in $_SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976132/user-not-recognized-through-parse-parseuser-but-exists-in-session)

However, usually you want the session to be instantiated before anything else runs, so you could try moving the `session_start();` call to the top of your file.

Example:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'connectParse.php'; 

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser(); 
print_r( "<p>" . $currentUser . " </p><p>is the user</p>" );

?>
```

Comment: As you can see in the note of the original poster: "I've tried with and without the session_start();"  I personally have tested it on top and below. The issue seems to be that the _SESSION data actually changes between the page. I will try to edit his post.

Comment: Laxus hits on the issue below and more can be read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2010505/2930828